# My code wont print

Tags: printing

I don't know why its not printing the number of heads and tails and everything I do it just does the same thing. Nothing!
Can someone please help this is part of an assessment that was due yesterday.

```
import random

heads = 0
tails = 0
rounds = 0

while rounds < 100:
coin = random.randint(1, 2)

if coin == 1:
heads += 1
rounds += 1

 elif coin == 2:
tails += 1
rounds += 1

print("You Flipped Heads {} Times!".format(heads))
print("You Flipped Tails {} Times!".format(tails))
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code; and tag it with python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably broken indentation causes the while loop to loop :) infinitely.

```
import random

heads = 0
tails = 0
rounds = 0

while rounds < 100:
  coin = random.randint(1, 2)

  if coin == 1:
    heads += 1
    rounds += 1

  elif coin == 2:
    tails += 1
    rounds += 1

print("You Flipped Heads {} Times!".format(heads))
print("You Flipped Tails {} Times!".format(tails))
```

And here's a working [example](https://repl.it/HkIf).